# Prove that $\Pi_{k=0}^{3}(\cos(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{18}))=\frac{3}{16}.$

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

This was a problem given in a handout. I could solve the 1st problem as follows:

> If $x=1$ and $n=9$, then $2=2\Pi_{k=0}^{\frac{n-3}{2}}[x^2-2x\cos(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n})+1]=2\Pi_{k=0}^{3}[2-2\cos(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{9})].$ Then, $\frac{1}{2^4}=\Pi_{k=0}^{3}[1-\cos(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{9})]=\Pi_{k=0}^{3}(2\sin^2(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{18})).$ Thus, we have the required identity directly following from here.

But I don't know how to prove the part $ii$ ?

Comment: Use $n=9$ but $x=-1$ and do the same thing

Comment: @FShrike If $x=-1$, then it becomes an identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially just do what you did but with $x=-1$. Some caution is required to handle the factors of zero.

Firstly rewrite: $$1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1+x^n}{1+x}=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n}+1\right)$$For odd integer $n$. You can consider that $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^n=\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$ when $a\neq1$ and if $n$ is odd and $a=-x$, $-a=x$ and $-a^n=-(-1)^nx^n=x^n$ so we find the stated equation.

Then as $x\to-1$, since the LHS and RHS are both continuous functions we can deduce that: $$\begin{align}n&=1-(-1)+(-1)^2-(-1)^3+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\\&=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\left(2+2\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n}\right)\\&=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n-3}{2}}4\cos^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\end{align}$$

Using: $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1\implies2\cos^2(y/2)=1+\cos(y),\,\forall x\in\Bbb R$$

Let $n=9$ in this formula. Then: $$9=4^4\left(\prod_{k=0}^3\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{18}\right)^2,\,\prod_{k=0}^3\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{18}=\frac{3}{16}$$

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat off point:

Since FShrike's response answers the OP's (i.e. original poster's) question, I can't resist providing an alternative approach to Part (ii).

Easier to express the problem in degrees.

$\underline{\text{Preliminary Results}}$

**PR-1**
$\displaystyle 4\cos^3(20) - 3\cos(20) = \frac{1}{2}.$
**Proof**
$\displaystyle \cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x),~$ and $~\displaystyle \cos(60) = \frac{1}{2}.$

**PR-2**
$\displaystyle \cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1.$

**PR-3**
$\displaystyle \cos^2(20) - \left[ ~\frac{1}{2} ~\cos(40) ~\right] = \frac{1}{2}.$ 
**Proof**
$\displaystyle \cos(40) = \left[ ~2\cos^2(20) - 1 ~\right] \implies $
$\displaystyle \cos^2(20) - \left[ ~\frac{1}{2}  ~\cos(40) ~\right]
 = \cos^2(20) - \left[\cos^2(20) - \frac{1}{2}\right].$

**PR-4**
$\displaystyle \cos(20) \times \left[\cos(40) - \frac{1}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{4}.$ 
**Proof**
$\displaystyle \cos(40) = \left[2\cos^2(20) - 1\right] \implies \left[\cos(40) - \frac{1}{2}\right] = \left[2\cos^2(20) - \frac{3}{2}\right] \implies $ 
$\displaystyle \cos(20) \times \left[\cos(40) - \frac{1}{2}\right]$ 
$\displaystyle = \cos(20) \times \left[2\cos^2(20) - \frac{3}{2}\right]$
$\displaystyle = 2\cos^3(20) - \frac{3}{2}\cos(20).$ 
Invoke **PR-1**.

**PR-5**
$\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b) = 2\cos(a)\cos(b).$ 
**Proof**
$\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b).$
$\cos(a-b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b).$

---

The assertion is that

$$\left[ ~\cos(10) \times \cos(30)~\right] \times \left[ ~\cos(50) \times \cos(70) ~\right] = \frac{3}{16}.\tag1 $$

Using **PR-5**, 
$\displaystyle \cos(10) \times \cos(30) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~\cos(20) + \cos(40) ~\right]$ 
and 
$\displaystyle \cos(50) \times \cos(70) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~\cos(20) + \cos(120) ~\right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~\cos(20) - \frac{1}{2} ~\right].$

Therefore, the LHS of (1) above evaluates to

$$\frac{1}{4} \times \left[ ~\cos(20) + \cos(40) ~\right] \times \left[ ~\cos(20) - \frac{1}{2} ~\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{4} \times \\ \left\{ ~
\left[ ~\cos^2(20) - \left\langle ~\frac{1}{2} ~\cos(40) ~\right\rangle ~\right] + 
\left[ ~\left\langle ~\cos(20) ~\cos(40) ~\right\rangle - \left\langle ~\frac{1}{2} ~\cos(20) ~\right\rangle ~\right]
 ~\right\}.$$

Invoking **PR-3** and **PR-4**, this equals

$$\frac{1}{4} \times \left\{ ~\left[ ~\frac{1}{2} ~\right] + ~\left[ ~\frac{1}{4} ~\right] ~\right\}.$$